# Multiple OR conditions for words in JavaScript regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I trying to have a regular expression which is finding between two words but those words are not certain one.

```
2015ÖĞLEYEMEKKARTI(2016-20.AdıMEVLÜTSoyadıERTANĞASınıfıE10/ENo303
```

This is my text. I'm trying to find the word between `Soyadı` and `Sınıfı`, in this case `ERTANĞA`, but the word `Sınıfı` also can be `no`, `numara` or any number. This is what I did.

```
soyad[ıi](.*)S[ıi]n[ıi]f[ıi]|no|numara|[0-9]
```

`[ıi]` is for Turkish character issue, don't mind that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a single capture group to get the word `ERTANĞA`, keep the character class `[ıi]` instead of using an alternation for `(ı|i)` and group the alternatives at the end of the pattern using a non capture group `(?:`

```
soyad[ıi](.+?)(?:S[ıi]n[ıi]f[ıi]|n(?:o|umara)|[0-9])
```

- `soyad[ıi]` Match `soyadı` or `soyadi`
- `(.+?)` Capture **group 1**, match 1 or more chars as least as possible
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `S[ıi]n[ıi]f[ıi]` Match `S` and then `ı` or `i` etc..
  - `|` Or
  - `n(?:o|umara)` Match either `no` or `numara`
  - `|` Or
  - `[0-9]` Match a digit 0-9
- `)` Close non capture group

Note that you don't need the `/m` flag as there are no anchors in the pattern.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jViyQl/1)

```js
const regex = /soyad[ıi](.+?)(?:S[ıi]n[ıi]f[ıi]|n(?:o|umara)|[0-9])/gi;
const str = "2015ÖĞLEYEMEKKARTI(2016-20.AdıMEVLÜTSoyadıERTANĞASınıfıE10/ENo303\n";
console.log(Array.from(str.matchAll(regex), m => m[1]));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like below :

```
/.*Soyad(ı|i)|S(ı|i)n(ı|i)f(ı|i).*|no.*|numera.*|[0-9]/gmi
```

Here is the link I worked on  : https://regex101.com/r/QXLjLF/1

[image]

In JS code:

```
const regex = /.*Soyad(ı|i)|S(ı|i)n(ı|i)f(ı|i).*|no.*|numera.*|[0-9]/gmi;

var str = `2015ÖĞLEYEMEKKARTI(2016-20.AdıMEVLÜTSoyadıERTANĞASınıfıE10/ENo303`;


var newStr = str.replace(regex, '');
console.log(newStr);
```

Comment: Sorry but I have to include insensitive flag also. Why is it returning me all text when I use it with your regex?

Comment: @Kaepxer sorry, my bad. didn't see the case insensitive requirement before. Please check now. How does string appear when its numbers after  ERTANĞA ? if all are numbers after that above will work, else we need to do little adjustment to remove all numbers after Soyadı

Answer (score 1):

This might do it

```js
const str = `2015ÖĞLEYEMEKKARTI(2016-20.AdıMEVLÜTSoyadıERTANĞASınıfıE10/ENo303
2015ÖĞLEYEMEKKARTI(2016-20.AdıMEVLÜTSoyadıERTANĞAnumaraE10/ENo303
2015ÖĞLEYEMEKKARTI(2016-20.AdıMEVLÜTSoyadıERTANĞAnoE10/ENo303`
const re = /(?:Soyad(ı|i))(.*?)(?:S(ı|i)n(ı|i)f(ı|i)|no|numara)/gmi
console.log([...str.matchAll(re)].map(x => x[2]))
```

ES5

```js
const str = `2015ÖĞLEYEMEKKARTI(2016-20.AdıMEVLÜTSoyadıERTANĞASınıfıE10/ENo303
2015ÖĞLEYEMEKKARTI(2016-20.AdıMEVLÜTSoyadıERTANĞAnumaraE10/ENo303
2015ÖĞLEYEMEKKARTI(2016-20.AdıMEVLÜTSoyadıERTANĞAnoE10/ENo303`
const re = /(?:Soyad(ı|i))(.*?)(?:S(ı|i)n(ı|i)f(ı|i)|no|numara)/gmi
const res = []
let match;
while ((match = re.exec(str)) !== null) res.push(match[2])

console.log(res)
```

Comment: My bad, I didn't mentioned but I'm coding in React Native and matchAll() is not working on Android. It needs external library for this, so I'm not prefering this solution until I have no choice.

Comment: `This is my text. I'm trying to find the word between "Soyadı" and "Sınıfı`  - this is the answer that will find the word. It is not a replace statement because that is not what you asked for. Replace statement will fail if the string changes

Comment: IDK what do you mean by "replace statement will fail if the string changes" but when I try it with different strings It gave me the correct word.

Comment: Soyadı means "surname" in Turkish. I'm trying to find surname. So, my bad again not to say that.